# Fast Serialization - Android

Tags: android, performance, memory, serialization

I have been given the assignment to process large amounts of text data on an Android phone. ( it is a requirement to do the processing on the phone for privacy reasons) I have a Keyword object that I have to compare against String messages this object contains two ArrayList, two int ids, and a boolean, The problem is that we have 50000+ of these objects. Keeping a list of theses objects in memory causes an OutOfMemory Exception on phones with less than 1.5 GB ram. The current implementation we have is to serialize the list to file and then deserialize each object one at a time as we need it. With this implementation we keep a low memory profile and have optimized it down to 5 seconds processing time per message. They want it to have low memory but process 3 or 4 a second ideally. I'm not saying this is a feasable requirement. I just thought that I would ask the experts at StackOverFlow and see if anyone had any ideas on how we could speed up this process.

For Serialization I have implemented Externalization. Here is the code.

```
@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput input) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    groupID = input.readInt();
    keywordID = input.readInt();
    mapped = input.read() == 1;
    int length = input.readInt();
    int piecelength;
    for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        piecelength = input.readInt();
        byte[] piece = new byte[piecelength];
        input.read(piece);
        keywordPieces.add(new String(piece));           
    }
    length = input.readInt();
    for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        piecelength = input.readInt();
        byte[] piece = new byte[piecelength];
        input.read(piece);
        positiveKeywordPieceFragments.add(new String(piece));           
    }
}

@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput output) throws IOException
{
    output.writeInt(groupID);
    output.writeInt(keywordID);
    output.write(mapped ? 1 : 0);
    output.writeInt(keywordPieces.size());
    for(int index = 0; index < keywordPieces.size(); index++)
    {
        byte[] piece = keywordPieces.get(index).getBytes();
        output.writeInt(piece.length);  
        output.write(piece);            
    }
    output.writeInt(positiveKeywordPieceFragments.size());
    for(String s : positiveKeywordPieceFragments)
    {
        byte[] piece = s.getBytes();
        output.writeInt(piece.length);  
        output.write(piece);            
    }
}
```

Here is the File Reading Code

```
input = new ObjectInputStream( new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(keywordsFile)));
int length = input.readInt();
Keyword keyword;
for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
{
    keyword = (Keyword) input.readObject();
    callback.onKeywordRead(keyword);
    keyword = null;
}
```

anything at all that you can think of that will speed this up would be awesome.

Edit:

The loop previous to the current implementation looked like this

```
for(Keyword keyword : keywords)
```

The keywords were just kept in memory, but, like I stated above, this caused an OutOfMemoryException on older devices when the list was being populated. It was stored in an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have 50K records, most of which cannot be loaded into RAM, and a data architecture which favors data READ over data WRITE.

If that is the case just use the database. Index the fields (preferably <=2 ) that you want to use for fast retrieving of data, something like:

```
  db.execSQL( "Create Index MyTable_StartDate_idx ON MyTable(StartDate);"
```

.. And you will get performance far exceeding anything you can do yourself within a reasonable time.